# Row size overhead

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have a MS SQL Server 2008 database on a shared hosting and I need to reduce the used storage space as much as possible. My largest table has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [stage](
    [station_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [time_utc] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [stage_mm] [smallint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_stage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([station_id] ASC,[time_utc] ASC)
```

I tried to find out the average number of bytes per record in my table. 
According to theory the size should be: 4B (row header) + 2B (smallint) + 4B (smalldatetime) + 2B (smallint) which is 12 bytes.

However, when I ran the command:

```
dbcc showcontig ('stage') with tableresults
```

It shows: MinimumRecordSize=15, MaximumRecordSize=15
So according to SQL Server, the bytes per record is 15 and not 12
The number 15 bytes per record seems also correct when I look at the total disk space taken by the table and divide it by number of rows.

What is taking up the 3 extra bytes ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those 3 extra are from the NULL Bitmap. [According to Paul's post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-null-bitmap-size/), it's on every row save for those that are all SPARSE across the columns (beginning in SQL Server 2008).

And according to a line in [this BOL post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933051(v=sql.80).aspx), the NULL Bitmap is = 2 + ((number_columns_in_clustered_index + 7) / 8). In your case, 3.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So it appears that in my case it's impossible to reduce the row overhead in SQL Server 2008 to less than 7 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I partially agree with @Matt, the 2 bytes are required for NULL bitmap which is correct.

However, the last byte is consumed by the number of columns per bit. Meaning, If I have 6 columns in  my table then I'll require 1 byte (6-bits), or If I have 12 columns then I'll require 2 bytes (12-bits).

In your case there are **3 columns** hence it has taken just **1 byte**.