# DBCC SHOWCONTIG : Row Count size

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbcc

Using the DBCC SHOWCONTIG command we get the size of a row in minimum, maximum and on average.
Just to make sure, the unit of Measurement is Byte right?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the unit of measurement is **Bytes**.

I use it but I don't found any official informations about that.

I continue searching and post a link if I find any interesting informations.

**EDIT :**

Bytes is also used here :
[Row size overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719315/row-size-overhead)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly unable to find any description of unit in MSDN as well.